# batch file close on ENTER key

Tags: batch-file

I have a batch file with the following in it:

```
copy con filename.txt
pause
```

This creates a tyext file with whatever the user types.  But when they hit ENTER, it only interprets that as a new line.

How can i get the command window to exit and close after the user types his entry?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
set /p something="A prompt if you want one "
>filename.txt echo %something%
pause
```

Comment: Ah, you beat me to it! I should have paid attention to notifications.

Comment: hi.  i would like to ad 1 more functionality.  a text file is created. i would like to know if a workbook can be opened or created that contains the value the user inputted. thanks

Comment: Try changing filename.txt to filename.csv then input a comma-separated data line. You should be able to open the resultant file in EXCEL.

Comment: thanks.  do you know th syntax i would put in the batch file prgramming that would automate that?

Comment: simply `filename.csv` should open the file in excel if excel is associated with `.csv` files. You may want to use slightly different syntax like `start "screen header" filename.csv` which should start up excel (if associated) and run the remainder of the batch rather than waiting for the excel window to be closed. If excel is not associated with excel (or whatever spreadsheet you're using) then `"d:\the\path\to your\spreadsheet.exe"` and a space should be put before the `.csv` filename.